# topic-comment naming of functions/methods

Tags: oop, programming-languages, naming-conventions

I was looking at American Sign Language the other day... and I noticed that the construction of the language was topic-comment.  As in "Weather is good".  That got me to thinking about why we name methods/functions in the manner of:

```
function getName() { ... }
function setName(v) { ... }
```

If we think about naming in a topic-comment function, the function names would be

```
function nameGet() { ... }
function nameSet() { ... }
```

This might be better for a class had multiple purposes. IE:

```
class events {
    function ListAdd();
    function ListDelete();
    function ListGet();

    function EventAdd();
    function EventDelete();
    function EventGet();
}
```

This way the functions are grouped by "topic".  Where as the former naming, functions are grouped Action-Noun, but are sorted by Noun.

I thought this was an interesting POV, what do other people think about naming functions/methods Topic-Comment?

Obviously, mixing naming conventions up in the same project would be weird, but overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern OOP techniques should enable us to not have to specify the subject of our function, but only the action, so for Ex.

Your events class should only have add/delete/get, and you should have a separate, `Event_List` class that would also have add/delete/get.

so, depending on the language it would be called `event_obj.get()`, or `event_obj.delete()`... etc..

like `event_list_obj.add()` etc...

This actually lines up with what you said about sign language, which is a very good point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to venture a guess and say that your events class should have a "List" object that has an add, get, and delete along with its own add, get, and delete.  I find it redundant  when you see the name of the class repeated in its methods.

Comment: It actually should be the other way around, there should be a List class that instantiates new event objects that are the items in the list.

Comment: The comment about redundancy is a very good comment, I've been organically growing (adding as needed) an object and this is a good reminder that I need to split it.